# Using repair or fix?

Tags: word-choice

Which is more common to use in the following sentence: repair or fix?

My air-conditioner has broken down so someone is coming to repair/fix it tomorrow.

Comment: As a British person I would use 'repair', but maybe an American would be more likely to say 'fix'?

Comment: As an Australian, I too would use 'repair', especially if the work was being performed by a trained and/or skilled worker. For example, compare, 'Dad fixed the garage door' with, 'the electrician repaired the hot-water heater'.  Like @Kate, I suspect that 'fix' for both situations might be more commonly used in American English.

Comment: @NMl: Thanks for your interesting and simple explanation.

Comment: In my experience of American English, you could say that the repairman came over to fix the door as easily as you could say he repaired it, you would say that the plumber fixed the pipes but she repaired the bathtub, you would say that the roofers repaired the roof but not that they fixed it.